# Get repeating values in dictionary array. Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have an array like this

```
[
    ["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": Chicken],
    ["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": Chicken],
    ["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": Chicken],
    ["itm_id": 7, "itm_name": Cat]
]
```

I have this array of dictionaries and I am trying to group them by a value in the dictionary. So in my example above I would like to know create a dictionary to know how many dictionaries I have with a repeating key:

`[["item_id" : 4, count: 3], ["item_id" : 7, count: 1]]`

`itm_id: 4` is repeated 3 times so the count is 3 and `itm_id: 7` is repeated only once.

How can I achieve that

Comment: Define "equal" for your dictionaries. Do you only require `itm_id` to match, or both `itm_id` and `itm_name` to match? What if I have a `["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": Duck]`? Is it equal to `Chicken`? And what if you have different `Chickens`?

Comment: I would suggest using a struct instead of a dictionary (like it has been answered already), make it conform to the `Hashable` protocol, and use `NSCountedSet` to know the number of times an object repeats in a given set.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a `struct` of the item array instead of dictionaries like this

```
struct Item{
    var itemID : Int
    var name : String

    init(dictionary:[String:Any]) {
        itemID = dictionary["itm_id"] as? Int ?? 0
        name = dictionary["itm_name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Once you have an array of `Items` you can map the elements of a particular item ID as an array to get the count and remove them from the array. Have a look at the code below. Not the cleanest implementation, but it would help you with your problem.

```
func countDuplicates(){
    let dictionary = [["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": "Chicken"],["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": "Chicken"],["itm_id": 4, "itm_name": "Chicken"],["itm_id": 7, "itm_name": "Cat"]]
    var items = [Item]()
    var countArray = [[String:Any]]()
    dictionary.forEach{
        items.append(Item(dictionary: $0))
    }
    while items.count > 0 {
        if let firstItem = items.first{
            let duplicateItems = items.filter{$0.itemID == firstItem.itemID}
            var countDictionary = [String:Any]()
            countDictionary["itm_id"] = firstItem.itemID
            countDictionary["count"] = duplicateItems.count
            countArray.append(countDictionary)
            items = items.filter{$0.itemID != firstItem.itemID}
        }
    }
    print(countArray)
}
```

This will print `[["itm_id": 4, "count": 3], ["itm_id": 7, "count": 1]]`

I assumed that the `Chicken`, `Cat` are Strings. In case they're not a string but a class type you can rewrite the `Item` struct to something like this

```
class Animal{}

class Chicken:Animal{}

class Cat:Animal{}

struct Item<T:Animal>{
    var itemID : Int
    var name : String
    var animal : Animal

    init(dictionary:[String:Any],animal:T) {
        itemID = dictionary["itm_id"] as? Int ?? 0
        name = dictionary["itm_name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.animal = animal
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize the Item like

`yourItem = Item(dictionary:yourDictionary,animal:Cat())`

Comment: Don't declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized with non-optional values in an `init` method. Never do that. Remove the exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

**// Swift 3.1**

Option 1 : Using Dictionaries

```
func countRepeats() -> [[String: Int]] {
    var repeats = [Int: Int]()
    arr.forEach { item in
        if let id = item["itm_id"] as? Int {
            repeats[id] = repeats[id] == nil ? 1 : repeats[id]! + 1
        }
    }
    return repeats.map {["item_id" : $0.key, "count": $0.value]}
}

print(countRepeats()) // [["item_id": 4, "count": 3], ["item_id": 7, "count": 1]]
```

Option 2: It is recommended to use Struct instead of Dictionary

```
public struct ItemCount {
    let id: Int
    let count: Int
}

func countRepeats() -> [ItemCount] {
    var repeats = [Int: Int]()
    arr.forEach { item in
        if let id = item["itm_id"] as? Int {
            repeats[id] = repeats[id] == nil ? 1 : repeats[id]! + 1
        }
    }
    return repeats.map {ItemCount(id:$0.key, count: $0.value)}
}

print(countRepeats())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest manipulating your data in classes (or Structs) but if you must use arrays of dictionaries, here's one way to get the counts:

```
// extract all the "itm_id" values from all dictionaries in the array
// use a set to identify unique values
// map each unique values to its count in the array

let ids = dictionaries.flatMap{$0["itm_id"] as? Int}
let idCounts = Set(ids).map{ id in (id, ids.filter{$0==id}.count) }

// You can use map() to turn this into yet another array of dictionaries

let idCountDict = idCounts.map{["itm_id":$0 ,"count":$1]}

print(idCounts)     // [(4, 3), (7, 1)]
print(idCountDict)  // [["itm_id": 4, "count": 3], ["itm_id": 7, "count": 1]]
```